# Docker install version

Tags: docker, download, version

[Docker download button1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuVXC.jpg)

[Docker download button2, 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bmXz.jpg)

I wonder whether the docker version, which is downloaded when the "Get Docker"button is clicked, is the stable version or the edge version.
After reading the documentation, there are two versions, the stable version and the edge version, but there was no selection when clicking the "Get Docker"button.

Answer (score 0):

Download links in release notes. Stable releases here
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/